# UICollectionView reload Failure

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uicollectionview

WhenEver I tries to reloadData with my UICollectionView it ends up with the following error. I am sure i am not releasing any variable. The NSMutableArray with the data is also not released. Any one faced similar issues? Can anyone provide me a work around?

```
2014-04-22 22:28:55.010 SalesApp[6901:19d03] *** -[UIViewAnimationContext completionHandler]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xa4475f0
```

The NSZombie gives me nothing useful..:-(

[image]
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried running with Zombies turned on, which may give a better idea of which object is being deallocated?

Comment: @Nick Above shows the Zombies screenshot...I dont think it could provide me enough information...The release occurs inside a non user method..:-(

Comment: It is deallocating some underlying graphical object..:-)

Comment: I cant figure out the problem, but i by passed  the problem by adding an empty invisible cell !!!